# Create array with index, and compare from other array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create an array with index to search values and compare with another array from `pgcon`:

```
@trunks = []

#trunks local
@trunks_local = []

#dados_local
@bd_local = {}

@c_local = PG.connect(:hostaddr => 'myhost', :port => 5432, :dbname => "testdb", :user => "test", :connect_timeout => 90)

@bd_local = @c_local.exec("SELECT trunk_id, name,phone_number,active FROM callback_trunks")

@bd_local.each.with_index(0) do |h|
  @trunks_local << h
end
```

This is the comparison:

```
@trunks.each.with_index(0) do |trunks|
@trunks_local.each.with_index(0) do |trunk_local|
```

Comment: Tip: Not every variable has to be an instance variable (`@`-prefixed). Think about which things you want to persist beyond the method call and which are temporary.

Comment: You're doing a lot of `each.with_index(0)` calls. `with_index` defaults to `0`, so you can do `each.with_index` and ignore the argument.

Comment: It's not really clear what the comparison is supposed to do. Can you strip out the Postgres stuff and show the data you're trying to compare? A more complete example in that regard would help a lot. Ruby arrays and hashes can be compared directly if you structure them properly.